# How to delete duplicates on oracle where duplicate criteria and identifier columns are different keeping latest record with its previous updates

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, rdbms

I am not very expert in DB and I am working on this query to remove duplicates.

Basically, I have Table event having data like

[image]

and I want results like

[image]

Its like I should be having a unique entry with Code, Unit, and type as a ACTIVE status.
So Row 1, 2, 3, 7, 8 are duplicates for me and I need to keep 1 entry out of duplicates with maximum validity_until. Need to get EventId for entries which need to be deleted to delete linked objects from other tables as well.
I am able to retrieve duplicates by query

```
SELECT code,unit,type FROM event where status='ACTIVE' GROUP BY code,unit,type having count(*) > 1 ;
```

but then how to retrieve event_id out of these duplicate records based on max(validity_until).
once I have Event_id like aaa, ccc to be deleted and need to keep hhh, I would be able to delete history of event aaa which is Row 11. But I want to keep Row 7 which is ggg event and its history is intact which is row 6.
and need to delete corresponding duplicate records from Solution table where identifier is Event_id from this event table.

Input :

| Row id | Event_Id | Code | unit | type | validity_until | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 111 | 1 | A | 12-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 2 | bbb | 222 | 2 | B | 02-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 3 | ccc | 111 | 1 | A | 15-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 4 | ddd | 333 | 2 | C | 12-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 5 | eee | 222 | 3 | A | 11-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 6 | ggg | 222 | 2 | B | 05-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | INACTIVE |
| 7 | ggg | 222 | 2 | B | 12-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 8 | hhh | 111 | 1 | A | 20-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 9 | ddd | 333 | 2 | C | 10-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | INACTIVE |
| 10 | eee | 222 | 3 | A | 01-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | INACTIVE |
| 11 | aaa | 111 | 1 | A | 13-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | INACTIVE |

Expected Result:

| Row id | Event_Id | Code | unit | type | validity_until | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | ddd | 333 | 2 | C | 12-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 5 | eee | 222 | 3 | A | 11-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 6 | ggg | 222 | 2 | B | 05-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | INACTIVE |
| 7 | ggg | 222 | 2 | B | 12-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 8 | hhh | 111 | 1 | A | 20-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | ACTIVE |
| 9 | ddd | 333 | 2 | C | 10-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | INACTIVE |
| 10 | eee | 222 | 3 | A | 01-JAN-21 12.01.01.625000 PM | INACTIVE |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number` as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by Code, Unit, type order by validity_until desc) as rn
  From t) t
Where rn = 1 or status <> 'ACTIVE'
```

Comment: Thanks Popeye, but event table is having millions of data already partitioned by some other column in 5 parts. Now making this in subquery, partitioning  on basis of combination of code,unit, type will get more than 1 lac partitions. I tried running this row_number type query in my plsql and query was executing from 20 mins but result was not calculated. At the end I needed to terminate the session.

Comment: Kindly suggest if we can have a better performance query or queries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing sample data and output result. Here goes your desired query:

```
WITH RESULTS AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY CODE,UNIT,TYPE ORDER BY validity_until DESC) AS RN,row_id ,event_id,  code,   unit,   type,   validity_until, Status FROM event  
)
SELECT * FROM RESULTS WHERE RN=1 OR STATUS='INACTIVE'
```

If there is no chance of having multiple row for same **code,   unit,   type and   validity_until** you can use dense_rank() instead of row_number. Though both use partition somewhere I have read that it's faster (not sure but you can give it a try):

```
WITH RESULTS AS (
SELECT dense_rank()OVER( PARTITION BY CODE,UNIT,TYPE ORDER BY validity_until DESC) AS RN,row_id ,event_id,  code,   unit,   type,   validity_until, Status FROM event  
)
SELECT * FROM RESULTS WHERE RN=1 OR STATUS='INACTIVE';
```

Comment: Thanks but event table is having millions of data already partitioned by some other column in 5 parts. Now making this results table and partitioning  on basis of combination of code,unit, type will get more than 1 lac partitions. I tried running this in my plsql and query was executing from 20 mins but result was not calculated. At the end I needed to terminate the session.

Comment: Kindly suggest if we can have a better performance query or queries.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am telling, I tried this on actual data which is millions in number and system got stuck. Not able to get it's response.